# Can Google App Script library access ScriptDB?

Tags: concurrency, google-apps-script, shared-libraries

Please go through the image for better understanding

[image]

**My problem:**

1. I have created a library which can access users Gmail for some data
2. I have also created an app script which uses the library
3. The app script has a scriptDB
4. Now I share the app script between **two users**
5. Now my question is, can I access the two scriptDBs from the library, if so how ?
6. Can the library find the scriptDBs as two different database. can it able to distinguish between two instances ?
7. Will be there any data mixing like user1's data is mixing with user2's data.
8. When the two users simultaneously accessing the library can it handle concurrency ?
9. When the library reads the users **Gmail** can it be able to show **user1's data to user1 only** and **user2's data to user2 only**.

Any help is greatly appreciated ! ! Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Basically it is about resource scoping as mentioned in [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).

Comment: I got some info from here still not exactly clear.....https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Comment: +1 for the drawing :-) good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an app's own ScriptDb instance to a library, and the library can store data into that app's ScriptDb instance.

So if you have a library named "Library," it can contain the following function:

```
function giveMeAnObject(db,item) {
  db.save(item);
  return db.count({});
}
```

And your app would use the library's function like this:

```
function doStuff(e) {
  Library.giveMeAnObject( ScriptDb.getMyDb(), {'foo' : 'bar'});       
}
```

There is one ScriptDb for the app (not for each user of the app), so if the library is accessed by two different apps (not two different users of the same app) the data would end up in two separate databases. However, if you just have two different users of the same app, their data will be mingled. Each App gets its own ScriptDb, but not each user.

Comment: Yes got it. In my case the library will be used by two different apps present in two different Google account. So I will have 2 different scriptDB. And about passing scriptDB as parameter, yes that is the only option that I can do, Thanks for your answer. I have accepted it.